# Windows Beamer presentation with notes

Tags: beamer, windows, viewers, presentations

Have anybody have success by finding a PDF Reader for Windows, that have possiblity to show notes on one screen and the presentation on the projector?

I am looking for one, otherwise I need to convert my presentation to Powerpoint

Comment: Acrobat reader do this, but you need to compile your presentation with the required flags.

Comment: Do you mean Adobe Reader? And what is the required flags for that?

Comment: Yes, and other also. See section 19.3 of the beamer user guide; I didn't test it personally, but what I understand of the code is that the presentation is compiled as a big page, with a double width or a double height.

Comment: I just tried it, but it did not work. Instead it shows the double width (or height)on the projector

Comment: You need to parametrize your computer display to extend the desktop one the 2 screens, with exactly the same dimensions on both screen

Comment: It will not change to widtest, as I have said in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367120/adobe-reader-will-not-change-use-this-screen

Comment: Changing the screen resolution is a matter of your OS, not of the PDF viewer

Comment: Yes, but I read in the instruktions for Adobe Reader it depends on the PDF

Comment: I don't understand how this post is unclear in any way. Also, so many commenters seems to have understood it. People closing a question should understand that stack overflow is not the right place to show off one's authority.